# Appium-Capybara-ruby running automation on Physical device and some of the capybara function not working

Tags: ruby, capybara, appium

I have setup Appium - Capybara and was able to run automation suites on physical device, but facing issue with few methods

I was able to successfully run Capybara methods like

```
fill_in field, :with => text
click_button button_text
expect(page).to have_content(text)
```

But facing issues with below method ( it works on regular chrome on laptop but not on mobile )

```
page.first(:link, link_text).click
```

can you please help me to understand if appium capybara supports all the capybara methods or only few of them.

Below is the error message

```
undefined method `click' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the above code, first the `link` with `link_text` is being searched on the page. If no link is found then nil is returned.
Thus, to make this code work, we need to wait for the link with the link text to appear on the page and then click it.
So you can use any one of the below mentioned code before clicking the fink

1. `page.should have_content(link_text)`
2. `page.find_link(link_text)`

If the above code doesn't works then you can also try increasing the default wait time as shown below:

```
Capybara.default_wait_time = 30
page.should have_content(link_text)
page.first(:link, link_text).click
Capybara.default_wait_time = DEFAULT_WAIT_TIME
```

DEFAULT_WAIT_TIME for Capybara tests is set in your environment file.

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

`undefined method 'click' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)` is telling you that `#first` isn't returning an element (`#first` returns immediately with a matching element, or nil if there is none).   Is there a reason you are using `first` rather than `find`??  If there is only one matching link on the page you should really prefer `find` over `first` (in this case `find_link`), or try to scope to a part of the page where the would only be one link, since it will throw an error explaining why it didn't find the link (rather than returning nil) and also has waiting behavior for elements to show up  (`first` can have the same behavior but it doesn't by default)

Comment: There are multiple links and we need to click on the first, which perfectly works on desktop, issue is more on the mobile or appium_capybara library

Comment: the issue is that it's not finding the link, that can be a couple of things - 1. the link isn't on the page, or isn't on the page quickly enough - change to `page.first(:link, link_text, minimum: 1).click` to test that (it'll wait a little bit for the link to link to show up if necessary).  2.  The link isn't matching because you're applying some CSS in one of the environments that is changing the case/etc of the link text and isn't happening in the other

Comment: I tried all the options, but my question is that if it works on the laptop browser then it should work on the mobile

if i am not wrong both of them are through capybara, so the lib support must be same

Comment: Why would you assume that what works on the laptop browser would work on the mobile?  Depending on how you're doing your mobile support, the page could be served from different templates, have different CSS, different JS libararies, etc  -- The error you're getting is not about lack of support in Capybara, it's the fact that the link you're trying to click can't be found on the page - why it can't be found is the question you need to answer.